# iPod "scan and fix" message in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ipod, check-disk

Everytime I plug in my iPod Windows 7 says it has problems and do i want to scan and fix.  How do I disable this?  I know my iPod is in good shape.

Answer (score 5):

> I know my iPod is in good shape.

Windows begs to differ :)

anyway, don’t click the “Scan and Fix” button.

open up a command line prompt and type the following command:

```
chkdsk (device drive letter): /f
```

*for instance the ipod is mounted as drive E type:* **chkdsk e: /f**

[Source](http://www.futureofrealestatetechnology.com/general-real-estate-technology/resolve-vista-scan-and-fix-error-when-plugging-in-ipod-or-other-devices/)

Comment: Might want to add that "enable disk use" needs to be checked and iTunes should be closed (otherwise chkdsk) will complain.

Answer (score 4):

Open a command prompt and type `chkdsk X:\ /f`.

- X = Drive letter of your iPod.
- f = Fix.

Comment: you just signed up to answer the question and then got beaten by 1 minute? life can be so not fair :) +1